# Angular Material Badge: Make MatBadge contain an icon instead of text?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Using `angular/material 6.2.1`, I am trying to add a badge to a button, which works fine. However, instead of showing plain text that I can set by using the `matBadge` directive, I would like the badge to show a material icon instead.

Does anyone know what I have to do to achieve this? I suppose I could use jQuery but I am wondering whether there might be a smoother/easier way to do so.

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing exposed in their API to achieve it at the moment. You have to manipulate the DOM by yourself:

```
$0.innerHTML = '<i class="material-icons">check</icon>'
```

You can write a simple directive to do it in a elegant and reusable way:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matBadgeIcon]'
})
export class MatBadgeIconDirective {

  @Input() matBadgeIcon: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const badge = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-badge-content');
    badge.style.display = 'flex';
    badge.style.alignItems = 'center';
    badge.style.justifyContent = 'center';
    badge.innerHTML = `<i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">${this.matBadgeIcon}</i>`;
  }
}
```

Usage: `<div matBadge matBadgeIcon="check">...</div>`

Otherwise there is a lot of plain text symbols that you can use like ★✎♥ ,...

Comment: setting `badge.style.display` breaks `matBadgeHidden`. I excluded this and works great.

Comment: They could have edited their css since. Don't hesitate to edit the post if you're sure that it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 32):

I solved this by simply setting f.e. matBadge="person" on the button.

And then in your css file:

```
.mat-badge-content {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

Comment: Clean, quick and straight to the point, thank you!

Comment: Still easy quick in 2023!

Answer (score 8):

This answer is for those who want to use **long string** inside the badge:

Changing only the CSS:

```
.custom-badge {

  .mat-badge-content {

    width: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px;
    left: 13px;
  }
}
```

in template:

```
<mat-icon 
class="custom-badge"
matBadge="1,2,4"
matBadgePosition="after" 
matBadgeColor="accent"
[matBadgeHidden]="myExpresion" 
>
 report_problem
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I vote [Alexandre Annic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52162235/12777955) response. But perform some changes

- Used renderer2 for security check reasons;
- Need set up the initial matBadge value for show the result in Angular17+;

this is breaking changed version of Alexandre code

**mat-badge-icon.directive.ts**

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matBadgeIcon]'
})
export class MatBadgeIconDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() matBadgeIcon: string = '';
  @Input() hideBadgeIcon: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private render: Renderer2
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const badge = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-badge-content');

    if (this.hideBadgeIcon) return;

    this.render.setStyle(badge, 'display', 'flex');
    this.render.setStyle(badge, 'alignItems', 'center');
    this.render.setStyle(badge, 'justifyContent', 'center');
    this.render.setProperty(badge, 'innerHTML',
      `<i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px">${this.matBadgeIcon}</i>`
    );
  }

}
```

**.html file**

```html
<div matBadge="0" matBadgeIcon="check" [hideBadgeIcon]="[your-condition]" [matBadgeHidden]="true">...</div>
```